# Необходимо ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое (в ответ на высказанное недоверие): "Не верите (—) ваше право". Требуется ли тут тире?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, тире здесь необходимо, так как это бессоюзное сложное предложение, в котором первая часть выражает условие, ср.: "Если не верите, то это ваше право".

Answer (score -1):

Да (двадцать символов)